# Why does the maximum of the normal distribution ($\mu$) trace out $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ with varying $p$

Tags: probability, trigonometry, normal-distribution

As I was recently playing around with the graph of the normal distribution, I noticed that as I varied $p$, the maximum of the graph traced out $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$.
In the following graphic I plotted the Gaussian bell function:
$$
{\displaystyle g(x)={\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}\exp {\left(-{\frac {1}{2}}{\frac {(x-\mu )^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}}\right)}.}
$$
with $\mu=n\cdot p$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\mu(1-p)}$. As I varied $p$ from $[0, 1]$ the maximum traced out $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$:

[Image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpNZ.png)

I was wondering where the trigonometric function originates from and why it shows up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $\mu$, the maximum value of the normal density is located at $x = \mu$:  $$g(\mu) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}.$$  Therefore, for $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$, the locus of the maximum as $p$ varies on $(0,1)$ is $$f(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n p(1-p)}}.$$  It is not $\csc p$ nor is it proportional to such a curve, as can be seen in a comparison here:
[image]

The blue curve is $2 \csc (\pi p)$, and the orange curve is $(p(1-p))^{-1/2}$.  There is no linear transformation between the two that will map one curve to the other:  they have different shapes.